# How do I get Apex Code Coverage in Visual Studio Code to show color highlighting and percentage after running a TestSuite?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, visualstudiocode

I am using the most updated SF plugin, Visual Studio Code and sf-cli against our internal sandbox environment. I have an Apex class that has tests in multiple files. I would like to run a test suite which contains all the tests and then see the code coverage color highlighting in Visual Studio.

I know I can do this via the command line and query code coverage but I am hoping there is a way to have Visual Studio Code do this.

NOTE: I am not asking about running a Test Class and seeing the coverage in the Apex Class. That I know how to do. I want to get the same effect via Test Suite.

Comment: Are you talking about having highlighted lines in the VSCode editor window (like we can get when using Salesforce's Developer Console), or just having a percentage that appears in the Output (or integrated Terminal) pane?

Comment: I was confused on the UI between running a single test (which can be done inline) and a Test Suite (which cannot be done inline). Once sfdxfox answered, I ran the Test Suite and code coverage colors showed up.

Comment: @DerekF It was the highlighted lines. I will edit to make more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Command Palette (Ctrl-Shift-P/Cmd-Shift-P), and find the command SFDX: Run Apex Test Suite, and select the suite. Your code coverage will automatically be updated. You won't get code coverage if `Salesforcedx-vscode-core: Retrieve-test-code-coverage` is not enabled. Open the Settings panel (Ctrl-,/Cmd-,) and type in "code coverage". This box should be checked.

Comment: wow it's you! thank you @sfdcfox!